# iText 5 getDefaultCell().setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER) has no effect

Tags: java, itext

I'm new with **iText** and I'm trying to build a table.
But for some reason `table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER)` has no effect, my table has still borders.

Here is my code:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 });
table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
Font tfont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.UNDEFINED, 10, Font.BOLD);
table.setWidthPercentage(100);
PdfPCell cell;
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Menge", tfont));
table.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Beschreibung", tfont));
table.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Einzelpreis", tfont));
table.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Gesamtpreis", tfont));
table.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("MwSt", tfont));
table.addCell(cell);
document.add(table);
```

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are mixing two different concepts.

**Concept 1:** you define every `PdfPCell` manually, for instance:

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Menge", tfont));
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
table.addCell(cell);
```

In this case, you define every aspect, every property of the cell on the cell itself.

**Concept 2:** you allow iText to create the `PdfPCell` implicitly, for instance:

```
table.addCell("Adding a String");
table.addCell(new Phrase("Adding a phrase"));
```

In this case, you can define properties at the level of the *default cell*. These properties will be used internally when iText creates a `PdfPCell` in your place.

**Conclusion:**

Either you define the border for all the `PdfPCell` instances separately, or you let iText create the `PdfPCell` instances in which case you can define the border at the level of the default cell.

If you choose the second option, you can adapt your code like this:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 });
table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
Font tfont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.UNDEFINED, 10, Font.BOLD);
table.setWidthPercentage(100);
table.addCell(new Phrase("Menge", tfont));
table.addCell(new Phrase("Beschreibung", tfont));
table.addCell(new Phrase("Einzelpreis", tfont));
table.addCell(new Phrase("Gesamtpreis", tfont));
table.addCell(new Phrase("MwSt", tfont));
document.add(table);
```

This decision was made by design, based on experience: it offers the most flexible to work with cells and properties.

Comment: Thanks for this answer @Bruno.  Explaining the concepts involved made it clear why my code wasn't working as expected.  I had the same problem as OP.

Answer (score 1):

> cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);

you have to set `NO_BORDER` on cell.

e.g.

> cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Menge", tfont));
>   cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
>   table.addCell(cell);

[refer itext here](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=82)

Comment: Yes i saw this too, but i just thought with getDefaultCell() i can set it as default for every cell. So this is not possible? I really have to do it for every cell?

Answer (score 0):

For all cell in Table:

```
 table.AddCell(new Phrase(DepInfo.ElementAt(0), font));
 table.AddCell(iText.Image.GetInstance(t));
 table.AddCell(third);
 foreach (var c in table.Rows.SelectMany(r => r.GetCells()))
   c.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new PdfPCell inheriting all the settings of the default table cell, you should use code like this:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 });
table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
Font tfont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.UNDEFINED, 10, Font.BOLD);
table.setWidthPercentage(100);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(table.getDefaultCell());
cell.setPhrase(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Menge", tfont)));
table.addCell(cell);
document.add(table);
```